# Detailed product page urls are hard to understand - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, page

When i go to the link

```
http://www.millefirme.com/shop/uomo.html
```

Click on a product to go to the link

```
http://www.millefirme.com/shop/catalog/product/view/id/2/s/giubbino-con-zip-in-contrasto-cappuccio/category/4/
```

This is a pretty long url.
I want to get back to it with .html
Please help me.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to run "Catalog URL Rewrites" indexer at System->Index Management

Thanks

Comment: Really thank you. But this does not work for me :(